# how to use pd.cut() across columns of a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

```
>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,4))
>> pd.cut(df,[0,0.5,1])

ValueError: Input array must be 1 dimensional
```

How can I get `pd.cut()` to work across all columns of a data frame?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `apply`

```
df.apply(pd.cut, bins=[0,0.5,1])
```

You can specify the `axis` if you want to run across columns (`axis=0`) or rows (`axis=1`)

Answer (score 7):

If you don't mind a slightly different type of labeling, `numpy.digitize` provides a vectorized `n-d` solution.

---

```
np.digitize(df, bins=[0, 0.5, 1.0])
```

```
array([[2, 2, 2, 2],
       [1, 2, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 2, 1],
       [2, 1, 2, 1],
       [2, 1, 2, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2],
       [1, 2, 1, 1],
       [2, 1, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 1, 1],
       [2, 1, 2, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

---

The label `1` would correspond to `0-0.5`, `2` to `0.5-1.0`, etc.

---

***Performance***

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1000, 1000))

%timeit pd.DataFrame(np.digitize(df, bins=[0, 0.5, 1.0]), columns=df.columns)
13.2 ms ± 36.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit df.apply(pd.cut, bins=[0, 0.5, 1])
3.11 s ± 12.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit pd.cut(df.stack(),[0,0.5,1]).unstack()
1.48 s ± 3.82 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 6):

Do it with `pd.cut` only accept one dimension

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,4))
pd.cut(df[0],[0,0.5,1])
```

Or

```
df.apply(lambda x : pd.cut(x,[0,0.5,1]),1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could stack and unstack:

```
pd.cut(df.stack(),[0,0.5,1]).unstack()
```

Results:

```
            0           1           2           3
0  (0.5, 1.0]  (0.0, 0.5]  (0.5, 1.0]  (0.5, 1.0]
1  (0.0, 0.5]  (0.0, 0.5]  (0.5, 1.0]  (0.0, 0.5]
2  (0.5, 1.0]  (0.5, 1.0]  (0.5, 1.0]  (0.5, 1.0]
```

For `cut`, this way should be equivalent to the other answers which apply `cut` on a column by column basis.  But if you were using `qcut`, they would give different answers.  (And which way is preferable would depend on your situation.)